# How to execute some code before removing an element from the visual tree?

Tags: wpf, events, user-controls, fadeout

I am trying to implement some fade-in and fade-out animations for a user control in WPF. For the fade-in animation I was able to use the Loaded event to accomplish that.

```
    public sealed partial class NowPlayingView : UserControl
    {
        public Duration AnimationDuration
        {
            get { return (Duration)GetValue(AnimationDurationProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AnimationDurationProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AnimationDurationProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("AnimationDuration", typeof(Duration), typeof(NowPlayingView), new PropertyMetadata(Duration.Automatic));

        public NowPlayingView()
        {
            Opacity = 0;
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += NowPlayingView_Loaded;
            Unloaded += NowPlayingView_Unloaded;

        }

        private void NowPlayingView_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoubleAnimation animation = new(1.0, 0.0, AnimationDuration);
            BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, animation);
        }

        private void NowPlayingView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoubleAnimation animation = new (0.0, 1.0, AnimationDuration);
            BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, animation);
        }
    }
```

I attempted to use the `Unloaded` event for the fade-out effect only to find out that the event is fired **after** the `UserControl` is removed from the visual tree (when the UserControl is no longer visible or accessible). Is there a way to run some code right before the UserControl "closes", something like the `OnClosing` event of a `Window`?

**EDIT:**

For a bit more context, the `UserControl` acts as a component of a more complex window. It is activated whenever the Property `NowPlayingViewModel` is not null and deactivated when null (which I do in order to hide the UserControl). It is when I set the ViewModel to null that I want to run the fade-out animation and I would like to keep the code-behind decoupled from other ViewModel logic.

```
<!-- Now playing View-->
<ContentControl Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{Binding NowPlayingViewModel}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:NowPlayingViewModel}">
            <views:NowPlayingView AnimationDuration="00:00:00.8" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

From my testing, I couldn't find any good solution to this so far, though I am open to suggestions that lead to similar behavior.

Comment: There's no such event for a usercontrol. You have to run any fade out animation before you remove your usercontrol. You could perhaps use the completed event of a storyboard to do the removal.

Comment: @FlorinZamfir: How and when do you hide the `UserControl`, i.e. when you you want it to fade? Can't you just animate it before you hide it?

Comment: @mm8 I provided a bit more context to the issue. Check the last edit on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simpler and more elegant solution to this problem.

```
    public sealed partial class NowPlayingView : UserControl
    {
        private bool _animating = false;

        public bool ShowWindow
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowWindowProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ShowWindowProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowWindowProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ShowWindow", typeof(bool), typeof(NowPlayingView), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnShowWindowChanged));

        private static void OnShowWindowChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is NowPlayingView userControl && (bool)e.NewValue == true)
                userControl.Show();            
        }

        public NowPlayingView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Opacity = 0;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _animating = true;

            Hide();

            _animating = false;
        }

        private void Show()
        {
            Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            DoubleAnimation animation = new()
            {
                From = 0.0,
                To = 1.0,
                FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd,
                Duration = new(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600))
            };
            Storyboard storyboard = new();

            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, this);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));
            storyboard.Begin();
        }

        private void Hide()
        {
            DoubleAnimation animation = new()
            {
                From = 1.0,
                To = 0.0,
                FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
                Duration = new(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600))
            };
            Storyboard storyboard = new();

            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, this);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));
            storyboard.Completed += delegate 
            { 
                Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; 
            };
            storyboard.Begin();
        }
    }
```

I created a dependency property `ShowWindow`. Whenever the property is changed to `true`, it will trigger the Storyboard for the fade-in animation. For fade-out I just hooked up a button OnClick event, but I could just as easily do this in the DependencyPropertyChanged method.

This way I keep the code somewhat decoupled and control the animation of the UserControl directly from its ViewModel with a property binded to the `ShowWindow` dependency property on the `UserControl`.